# Sample from tensorflow LSTM model when using symbolic batch inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building a next-character prediction LSTM for sentences.
I was following the tutorial here https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/ on how to make the data input process part of the tensorflow graph, and now I have a stateful LSTM that is fed with symbolic (!) batches generated by [tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.training.html#batch_sequences_with_states), which are in turn read from TF.SequenceExamples of varying lengths (Char-RNN working on characters in a sentence), as shown in the code below.

The whole input and batching process is therefore part of the compute graph.
The training works, but since the input is symbolic (not a TF.placeholder), I cannot figure out how to feed in my own sentence defined as a string to the LSTM to perform inference (sample from model). Any ideas?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.util import nest
import SequenceHandler
import DataLoader

# SETTINGS
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 128
num_unroll = 200
num_enqueue_threads = 10
lstm_size = 256
vocab_size = 39

# DATA
key, context, sequences = SequenceHandler.loadSequence("input.tf")  # Loads TF.SequenceExample sequence using TF.RecordReader

# MODEL
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=lstm_size)
initial_states = {"lstm_state_c": tf.zeros(cell.state_size[0], dtype=tf.float32), "lstm_state_h": tf.zeros(cell.state_size[0], dtype=tf.float32)}
batch = tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states(
    input_key=key,
    input_sequences=sequences,
    input_context=context,
    input_length=tf.cast(context["length"], tf.int32),
    initial_states=initial_states,
    num_unroll=num_unroll,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_threads=num_enqueue_threads,
    capacity=batch_size * num_enqueue_threads * 2)

# BATCH INPUT
inputs = batch.sequences["inputs"]
targets = batch.sequences["outputs"]

# Convert input into float one-hot representation
embedding = tf.constant(np.eye(vocab_size), dtype=tf.float32)
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs)

# Reshape inputs (and targets respectively) into list of length T (unrolling length), with each element being a Tensor of shape (batch_size, input_dimensionality)
inputs_by_time = tf.split(1, num_unroll, inputs)
inputs_by_time = [tf.squeeze(elem, squeeze_dims=1) for elem in inputs_by_time]
targets_by_time = tf.split(1, num_unroll, targets)
targets_by_time = [tf.squeeze(elem, squeeze_dims=1) for elem in targets_by_time]
targets_by_time_packed = tf.pack(targets_by_time)

# Build RNN
state_name=("lstm_state_c", "lstm_state_h")
state_size = cell.state_size
state_is_tuple = nest.is_sequence(state_size)
state_name_tuple = nest.is_sequence(state_name)
state_name_flat = nest.flatten(state_name)
state_size_flat = nest.flatten(state_size)

initial_state = nest.pack_sequence_as(
    structure=state_size,
    flat_sequence=[batch.state(s) for s in state_name_flat])

seq_lengths = batch.context["length"]
(outputs, state) = tf.nn.state_saving_rnn(cell, inputs_by_time, state_saver=batch,
                       sequence_length=seq_lengths, state_name=state_name)

# Create softmax parameters, weights and bias, and apply to RNN outputs at each timestep
with tf.variable_scope('softmax') as sm_vs:
    softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [lstm_size, vocab_size])
    softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size])
    logits = [tf.matmul(outputStep, softmax_w) + softmax_b for outputStep in outputs]
    logit = tf.pack(logits)
    probs = tf.nn.softmax(logit)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    # Compute mean cross entropy loss for each output.
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logit, targets_by_time_packed)
    mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [],
                              initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

learning_rate = tf.constant(learning_rate)
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(mean_loss, tvars),
                                  5.0)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)

train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars),
                                     global_step=global_step)

# TRAINING LOOP

# Start a prefetcher in the background
sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init_op)

# LOGGING
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("log", sess.graph)

vocab_index_dict, index_vocab_dict, vocab_size = DataLoader.load_vocab("characters.json", "UTF-8")

while True:
    # Step through batches, perform training
    trainOps = [mean_loss, state, train_op,
           global_step]
    res = sess.run(trainOps) # THIS WORKS - LOSS DECLINES

    testString = "Hello"
    # HOW TO SAMPLE FROM MODEL, GIVEN INPUT testString HERE?
```

In general, I have trouble understanding how to work with the data input as part of the compute graph, in terms of how to split it for cross-validation etc., and there seem to be no examples in that direction using TFRecords.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. It seems like `state_saving_rnn` is the problem since it takes the batch as input, however the `cell` could take any input. Couldn't you switch between a **training** and **predict** mode? Use `state_saving_rnn` when you train, and `for step in range(num_steps): outputs, state = cell(sequence[step], state)` when you predict? In the latter case `sequence` can be a normal tensor.