# how to provide test input to an rnn model trained thru sequenceexample

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to follow the approach of feeding training data thru sequence examples as described in the link 
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data for training an LSTM based RNN model via input pipelines and queues. since these examples are symbolic references, I'm unclear how we can feed a single or batch of test inputs on a trained model. A similar query was asked on the forum ([Sample from tensorflow LSTM model when using symbolic batch inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819196/sample-from-tensorflow-lstm-model-when-using-symbolic-batch-inputs)) but the solution is unclear. any suggestions here

Answer (score 0):

after some search this is the best i could get from the link https://github.com/dennybritz/tf-rnn/issues/3

Different ways to do this:

1) Create a different graph for training/inference (this is typically recommended) with different tensors as inputs.
2) Use tf.contrib.learn.Estimator and it's input function
3) Something like sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={batched_data: YOUR_CUSTOM_DATA}) should work